# How to get informations from a device connected to computer using VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, device, hid

There is no direct resource, i was able to find on internet for this issue.

**My questions are:**

1. How can i get the information about the device connected to PC.
2. How can i check whether it is connected to PC or not?
3. How i can get those data which is being transmitted by the devices to the computer?
4. Do the above questions require any other expertise than VB.NET?

**SOFTWARE WE ARE USING:**

1. Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

I have read many things about HID class and some other stuff, but i am afraid, maybe i am unable to understand the logic or maybe its not actually the right point to start for this topic.

I need an expert advice and note on the above queries and it would be great if someone can guide me for a road-map for the same. Like how to start and what information is required to start a programming for such devices.

I know the question is very long, but i thought it is wise to give the exact idea of what we want to do. Also, if to answer this question any prerequisite is required, i'll try my level best to get it available to you people ASAP.

I will give you an idea about the devices:

**Type of device:** Medical Device

**Role of Software for that device:** The software acts as a receiver for the devices, as the device gets data inputted by the user with its in-built keyboard and then the device sends that data to the PC. This software fetch that data sent by the device and displays in a desktop application.

**EDIT PART 1--------**

**Connection type:** There is a serial port on the device which is connected with other end serial port to the PC, also, we use converter from Serial port to USB to connect the dives with systems having USB ports.

**EDIT PART 1 END--------**

***BELOW ARE SOME DETAILS OF MY SITUATION FOR DEVELOPING THIS SOFTWARE, ITS NOT NECESSARY TO READ BUT YOU MAY CAN FIND THE EXACT REQUIREMENT OF MINE***

I have been working with a company in IT department, and developing VB.NET applications for them. I have good command on VB Application development.

However, my company is having a device which works with a PC application. This PC application has been developed by some other company and when it was developed there was no IT department in our company. Since 3 years we have an IT department and I being a programmer develop many VB.NET desktop applications for company.

Now, company wants to get a completely new software developed for its device with some new features.

Now company don't want to get this new software developed by any other company because of the fear that the idea will be stolen. So they have asked us to develop it.

I appreciate their demand and as we are related to IT and had total exposure to what we do, we want to develop this software for our-self.

But i had gone through so many things on internet and unable to find any starting instructions.

Comment: already check out for a serial communication with that device?

Comment: @Zachdev hey please reconsider, i have done one edit to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some more detail. e.g. How does the device "connect" to the pc? Serial cable, parallel (printer) cable. USB cable, network, proprietary hardware interface (a dedicated card in the back of the machine), something else?

Comment: have you looked at serial communication articles, like this one? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/ it shows how to use classes in the System.IO.Ports namespace.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier That is what i was looking for start but its in C#, no problem i can convert it into VB.NET, i was always searching with keyword `VB.NET` so didn't find this result. Anyways thanks a million... let me give it a try.

Comment: @GH: I've found when you need something for Vb, you often still have to search under .net & C# too.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Whenever i required something, i always found it under VB.NET but this time yes i really need to, because now when i am exploring with C# i am getting great results. Thanks for a very much required guidance :)

Comment: Your question is not clear, there is no technical information, I am not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Frist of all, you need to know the format of the messages sent by the device. If there is no documentation already available on that, get a tool like [HDD's Free Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/), or you can just use Windows' built in Hyper Terminal (at Accessories->Communication). Use that tool to see what goes down the serial cable when you do stuff on the device.

Once you figure out the messages' format, all you have to do is use [.NET's SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) to read the data and parse it into something useful.

Comment: Ok that a good thing to start, let me explore... thanks 1 UP :)